# jQuery Dialog + AngularJs Error dialog not a function

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am working on AngularJs application with jQuery UI.
But sometime I am getting dialog not a function error.
I have included Jquery Ui library before my controller and observed that
jQuery.ui object is available before angular bootstraping but sometime inside controller
jQuery.ui is not available (dialog is undefined) [Please find the plunker link](https://next.plnkr.co/plunk/MXBKuApCwuNy6x9y)

Answer (score 0):

Add style to you dialog div with display:none and check.

```
<div id="dialog" **style="display:none;"**> Dialog not a function. Intermittent </div>
```

Comment: I am not finding dialog definition sometime in my code. So, your input is not an answer

Comment: You have to load jquery in your controller or you have to explicitly load on application start at the application level, the choice is yours!!!.

Comment: Yes I have loaded jQuery UI library in start of my application.  You can see same second in loadsync function link after jQuery in home.js.